# Predictive model from sequential data R

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series

I have a prediction problem as follows:

My predictors are sequences and my outcome variable a binary.

Example data: sequences of 100 values and 1 outcome variable.

```
set.seed(1)
data = matrix(sample(seq(-10, 10, 0.1), 20000, replace = T)
              , 20, 100)
data = as.data.frame(data)
data$outcome = sample(c(0,1), 20, replace = T)
```

Now I want to see how well the sequences predict the outcome.

If I do a normal classification such as (without any data split for this illustration):

```
library(caret)
pred_model = train(outcome ~ .
                   , data = data
                   , method = "svmLinear")
```

... I neglect the fact that the 100 predictors need to be in that sequence rather than non-ordered.

My question is: which algorithms can I use that can map a sequence to a single value?

In principle, I could treat the sequence as a time series, but then too: which algorithms can predict an outcome based on a time series.

I guess this is a common problem in disciplines other than mine, so any pointers would be much appreciated.

(Preferably, I'd look for an implementation in R)

Comment: You said the outcome is binary and the predictors are a time series or a sequence. What exactly are the predictors?

Comment: It is a sequence in a specific order and the order has a temporal component to it (i.e. the second value follows the first value).

Comment: Are they spaced at (relatively) equal intervals?

Comment: Yes, the intervals are exactly equal.

Answer (score 0):

For dichotomous outcomes in a lonitudinal model, try using a glmm in `glmer` function in r. I can enhance this answer based on your comments.